# How to tie ansible service account credentials to ssh key for Gitlab CI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have a gitlab CI project set up and working for terraform by following the steps outlined here:

```
https://ael-computas.medium.com/gcp-workload-identity-federation-on-gitlab-passing-authentication-between-jobs-ffaa2d51be2c
```

It essentially sets the following variables to be used:

```
    - export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.gcp_temp_cred.json
    - export CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.gcp_temp_cred.json
    - export GOOGLE_GHA_CREDS_PATH=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.gcp_temp_cred.json
    - export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
    - export CLOUDSDK_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
    - export CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
    - export GCP_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
    - export GCLOUD_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
```

This all works fine in my terraform setup, but when trying to run my ansible tasks, it doesn't seem to be using the service account. It's just using a generic service account and I can't figure out how to change it. I get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) User [ephemeral-runner@gitlab-ci-plan-free-6-xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access users instance [ephemeral-runner@gitlab-ci-plan-free-6-xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com] (or it may not exist)
```

This is not the service account that I've set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable to. Any ideas how to get it to use that account in a gitlab runner?

Thanks!

Comment: A little more context from the error message: ```End user credentials must match the user specified in the request. Request for user [ ephemeral-runner@gitlab-ci-plan-free-6-xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not match the credential for [[MASKED]]```

The value of [[MASKED]] is what I want this to be running as. Not ephemeral-runner@gitlab-ci-plan-free-6-xxxxx. No idea how to make this happen though. I've been stuck on this problem for what seems like half my life.